# how to reset all validations on click of submit button in reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have completed my project in all respects but strangely enough at the last stage I am finding it difficult to remove the visible validators on clicking the "Submit Button", even if the input fields in the registration form are completed in all respects.

I have also tried to remove the validators through the form "Reset" but again it's not working. The code which I have tried is :

**html**

```js
(click)="Rst()";
```

**typescript**

```js
Rst(){
  this.formName.reset()
}
```

Please guide how I should go about it.

edit: I tried the code in this [link]
https://medium.com/@kash6062/angular-reset-validation-on-form-reset-533f5d6d76a5

edit 2:I have also tried the code in this [link]
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/25/angular-8-dynamic-reactive-forms-example

but the code is not working

Comment: Have you defined a default value to your controls?

Comment: You need to add some code of form and ts side .

Comment: which angular version are you using?

Comment: @KamranKhatti I am using angular 9

Comment: are you using angular material components?

Comment: Here is a very nice tutorial by JasonWatmore.
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/25/angular-8-dynamic-reactive-forms-example

Comment: @HansakaSandaruwan no I have not used angular material components.I have used bootstrap ,html and typescript.

Comment: @StPaulis nice tutorial  indeed.But its not working and I don't know why.

Rst(){
this.submitted =false;
  this.formName.reset()
}

that is how I tried it. Is there another way?

Comment: `this.formName.reset()` should work look like you have issue with your code can you please add complete .html and .ts file so that we can have better idea.

Comment: it would be easier for us to debug if you add a https://stackblitz.com/ project with your code

Comment: @StPaulis Thanks for a nice lead.I tried but its not working.

Rst(){
this.submitted =false;
  this.formName.reset()
}
this is the code I applied as per your suggestion but don't know why its not giving desired results.Please guide where I am missing the link.

Comment: @StPaulis Also please note in the given code:
onReset() {
        // reset whole form back to initial state
        this.submitted = false;
        this.dynamicForm.reset();
        this.t.clear();
    }

    onClear() {
        // clear errors and reset ticket fields
        this.submitted = false;
        this.t.reset();
    }
in the last line you will observe that its codified as "this.t.clear()" and "this.t.reset();
now please elaborate about the method  of “.t.”  given in the above two codes and what is its function?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code after **Reset**.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
      }
         this.cd.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call a method called "updateValueAndValidity()"

```
this.formName.updateValueAndValidity()
```

or if you want to update specific FormControl

```
this.formName.controls['your_form_control'].updateValueAndValidity()"
```

And after the code above, you may try to solution from @surendra kumar, which it will explicitly try to reflect or "refresh" the states to a later one.

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { .. }
....
Rst() {
    // After calling updateValueAndValidity
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```